# calculation of edge betweenness centrality subset in networkx

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory

In a simple graph with 5 nodes like this :

```
g=nx.Graph()
e=[(1,2),(1,3),(2,4),(2,5),(5,3)]
g.add_edges_from(e)
```

If I run the `nx.edge_betweenness_centrality_subset(g,[2],[3])` the results will be:

```
{(1, 2): 0.25, (1, 3): 0.25, (2, 4): 0.0, (2, 5): 0.25, (3, 5): 0.25}
```

However, based on the definition, subset betweenness of `(1,2),(1,3),(2,5)` and `(3,5)` should be `0.5` since there are two shortest paths between node 2 (source) and 3 (target) and each of these paths lies on one of them so it should be 1/2 based on the formula. Please help me to understand the results.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the 2 shortest paths are both 2 edges long the 0.5 you are expecting (1 of 2 paths) is divided again (1 of 2 edges) resulting in 0.25 for each edge.

*Just a guess.*

Comment: yes but the equation is about the number of shortest paths (which may involve even more than 2 links)

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue that introduces a factor of 2.

https://github.com/networkx/networkx/issues/3481

The documentation is being updated in version 2.4 to explain what the calculation is.  The ticket was closed 4 earlier this week, so I expect it to be finalized soon.

See also [is this betweenness calculation correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56569070/is-this-betweenness-calculation-correct)